# Saving image on db mysql through swift

Tags: php, mysql, image

i have a problem with my php file.
I'm trying to upload an image through xcode to mysql db.

here's swift code

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")

    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)

    if imageData != nil{
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"link php file")!)
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
        var contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)
        request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var body = NSMutableData.alloc()


        // Image
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"img.jpg\"").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        //body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(imageData)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        request.HTTPBody = body

        var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

        var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println("returnString \(returnString)")

    }
```

and here's php code:

```
$myparam = $_FILES['userfile']; //getting image Here //getting textLabe Here 

$target_path = "uploads/".basename($myparam['filename']);  

if(move_uploaded_file($myparam['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
    $var = 1; 
} 
else {
    $var = 0; 
} 

$myarray = array("response" => $var, "path" => $target_path);
$out = json_encode($myarray);
echo($out);
```

the problem is in the path. it returns wrong path and so i found no image in "uploads" folder. if i change target_path in php file (for example $target_path = "uploads/image.jpg"), image is saved.

i think it's a very easy problem but i don't understand what i have to change.

thanks for any help

hi

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` will show you exactly where you're going wrong: it's `['name']`, not `['filename']`. And your code is simply assuming nothing could ever go wrong and that uploads will never fail. That is a very **BAD** assumption.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know i'm assuming that up never fail but it's just a test; of course it has to be more complicated than that.

Anyway I don't understand your advice. What have i to change in my code? php or swift? and where? thanks